# HTML Dashboard Throughput, Response Times and User Load

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

Is it possible to generate a dashboard in JMeter to capture the throughput, response times and user load all at once?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o906of55x1n8z2zm8fyj3w9k3lqf8y0c) it's not possible.

As a workaround you can use [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) to send test metrics to a database like [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/). Then you can plot whatever charts you want in [Grafana](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-grafana)

Alternatively you can customize the dashboard by manipulating the files in the [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.6.3/bin/report-template) folder, you will need to be familiar with [Apache FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/index.html) for that.